# Woocommerce remove rows from order emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce is there a way to remove certain rows from the meta table in an email? Specifically I am trying to remove the "total" row in the `customer-refunded-order.php` email. This is the action `do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );`, is there a way to edit this action, or create a new one, where I can edit and display what order meta rows I want to include?

If not, is there a way I can change the string 'total' to something else?

Answer (score -1):

You can manipulate your order's meta fields with this:

```
function my_action_woocommerce_email_order_meta($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text) { 
    // Manipulate $order here
    return $order;
}

add_action('woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'my_action_woocommerce_email_order_meta');
```

Comment: Can you point my in the right direction about how I would find out how to remove rows preferably, and if not, rename them? And when this is set, would I change the `do_aciton` function in my email to `do_action('my_action_woocommerce_email_order_meta')`?